# getting percentage value for grouped by values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table and I am using the group to get the grouped sum for every country

```
Select country,count(country) from `xyz.xyz.call_stats` where  fan_out = 1 and last_channel_uri not like 'sip:confctl-d%' and call_end_time between '2021-05-17 00:00:00' and '2021-05-18 00:00:00' group by country
```

and it's giving me values in the below format:-

```
Row     country     f0_     
1       DZ          4941
    
2       NO          30737
    
3       IS          436
    
4       IT          32086
    
5       GF          11
    
6       CZ          9156
```

What I need is the percentage value for each country like for country DZ, 4941 is how much percent for the time period and the same for all of it.  My expected result would be:-

```
    Row     country     f0_     f1_
    1       DZ          4941    10%
        
    2       NO          30737  25.7%
        
    3       IS          436    2%
        
    4       IT          32086  29.6%
        
    5       GF          11     0.04%
        
    6       CZ          9156   3.67%
```

P.S:- I want to ignore the condition fan_out = 1 when calculating total for percentage but want to keep it when doing group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions.  I prefer a ratio between 0 and 1:

```
Select country, count(*),
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from `xyz.xyz.call_stats`
where fan_out = 1 and
      last_channel_uri not like 'sip:confctl-d%' and
      call_end_time between '2021-05-17 00:00:00' and '2021-05-18 00:00:00'
group by country;
```

You can multiply by `100` if you want a value between 0 and 100.

EDIT:

If you want the percentage based on a particular condition, use `countif()`:

```
Select country, countif(fan_out = 1),
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from `xyz.xyz.call_stats`
where last_channel_uri not like 'sip:confctl-d%' and
      call_end_time between '2021-05-17 00:00:00' and '2021-05-18 00:00:00'
group by country;
```

Comment: So, what should I do if I want to ignore the fan_out=1 condition when calculating the total for percentage but I want to keep it when doing group by.    I know that's not the part of the question but it would be great if you can help me with that. if you want I can edit the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the query with the below solution:-

```
WITH 
T1 AS (Select country,count(country) as NumA from `xyz.xyz.call_stats` where  fan_out = 1 and last_channel_uri not like 'sip:confctl-d%' and call_end_time between '2021-05-17 00:00:00' and '2021-05-18 00:00:00' group by country), 
T2 AS (Select count(*) as NumB from `xyz.xyz.call_stats` where last_channel_uri not like 'sip:confctl-d%' and call_end_time between '2021-05-17 00:00:00' and '2021-05-18 00:00:00') 
SELECT country,CAST(T1.NumA AS FLOAT64) / CAST(T2.NumB AS FLOAT64) * 100 as PctMetTgt
FROM T1, T2 order by PctMetTgt DESC
```